# How do I hide a menu when #links (same page links) get clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone please tell me how I can make my hamburger menu disappear again if any of the `#links` (same page links) get clicked or someone clicks outside the menu area? I think I need to be adding something to my JS script code but I can't seem to find the correct thing to alter or add. I am total novice when it comes to JavaScript.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!menuOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    document.getElementById("mymobilemenu").style.display = "block";
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    document.getElementById("mymobilemenu").style.display = "none";
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  border: 3px solid blueviolet;
  background: pink;
}

.menu-btn-burger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn-burger::before,
.menu-btn-burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn-burger::before {
  transform: translateY(-16px);
}

.menu-btn-burger::after {
  transform: translateY(16px);
}


/* animation of burger */

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}

#mymobilemenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-btn">
  <div class="menu-btn-burger">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mymobilemenu">
  <li><a href="#section1">section1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section2">section2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section3">section3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section4">section4</a></li>
</div>

<a id="section1">SECTION 1</a>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<a id="section2">SECTION 2</a>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<a id="section3">SECTION 3</a>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<a id="section4">SECTION 4</a>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can do that by adding foreach to `<li>`, so every time anyone click on that, script will remove open class to menu.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!menuOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    document.getElementById("mymobilemenu").style.display = "block";
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    document.getElementById("mymobilemenu").style.display = "none";
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
let  menuli = document.querySelectorAll('#mymobilemenu li');
menuli.forEach((item, index) => {
 item.addEventListener('click', () => {
 menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    document.getElementById("mymobilemenu").style.display = "none";
    menuOpen = false;
 
});

});
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  border: 3px solid blueviolet;
  background: pink;
}

.menu-btn-burger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn-burger::before,
.menu-btn-burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn-burger::before {
  transform: translateY(-16px);
}

.menu-btn-burger::after {
  transform: translateY(16px);
}


/* animation of burger */

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn-burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}

#mymobilemenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-btn">
  <div class="menu-btn-burger">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mymobilemenu">
  <li><a href="#section1">section1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section2">section2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section3">section3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section4">section4</a></li>
</div>

<a id="section1">SECTION 1</a>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<a id="section2">SECTION 2</a>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<a id="section3">SECTION 3</a>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<a id="section4">SECTION 4</a>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying adding this to your js script:

```
const a = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
a.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    document.getElementById("mymobilemenu").style.display = "none";
    console.log("removed");
  })

});
```

Comment: this is the shortest and simplest way

Comment: Have you test your code?. Another problem, if he have another link with for example target _blank in the text?